# Can v4l2 be used to read audio and video from the same device?

Tags: linux, audio, video, v4l2

I have a capture card that captures SDI video with embedded audio. I have source code for a Linux driver, which I am trying to enhance to add video4linux2 support.  My changes are based on the vivi example.

The problem I've come up against is that all the example I can find deal with only video or only audio.  Even on the client side, everything seems to assume v4l is just video, like ffmpeg's libavdevice.

Do I need to have my driver create two separate devices, a v4l2 device and an alsa device?  It seems like this makes the job of keeping audio and video in sync much more difficult.

I would prefer some way for each buffer passed between the driver and the app (through v4l2's mmap interface) contain a frame, plus some audio that matches up (with respect to time) with that frame.

Or perhaps have each buffer contain a flag indicating if it is a video frame, or a chunk of audio.  Then the time stamps on the buffers could be used to sync things up.

But I don't see a way to do this with the V4L2 API spec, nor do I see any examples of v4l2-enabled apps (gstreamer, ffmpeg, transcode, etc) reading both audio and video from a single device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the audio capture part of a device shows up as a separate device.  It's usually a different physical device (posibly sharing a card), which makes sense.  I'm not sure how much help that is, but it's how all of the software I'm familiar with works...

Comment: Is there any possibility to synchronize video and audio in this case?

Comment: Is there any possibility to know which audio device corresponds to a specific video device? What exactly does ioctl VIDIOC_S_AUDIO? How can I read audio data from the audio input selected by VIDIOC_S_AUDIO?

Answer (score 0):

There are some spare or reserved fields in the v4l2 buffers that can be used to pass audio or other data from the driver to the calling application via pointers to mmaped buffers.

I modified the BT8x8 driver to use this approach to pass data from an A/D card synchronized to the video on Ubuntu 6.06.

It worked OK, but the effort of maintaining my modified driver caused me to abandon this approach.

If you are still interested I could dig out the details.

IF you want your driver to play with gstreamer etc. a separate audio device generally is what is expected.

Most of the cheap v4l2 capture card's audio is only an analog pass through with a volume control requiring a jumper to capture the audio via the sound card's line input.